# Uncomprehensible logging behaviour

Tags: java, android, logging

I do have an activity class, with logic mostly residing in other classes in particular the Player class. I had a bug I decided to trace by logging, and the logging messages I added never showed up, so I went up the calling stack until they started showing up, until I found the last message that showed, when the player touches the screen here:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  Log.i("GA.onTouch()", "phase == false");  
  Player.test();
  return true;
}
```

There was no comprehensible reason why the call wouldn't succeed without error, so I created this test function:

```
public static void test() {
    Toast.makeText(mParent, "so weird", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("Player.test()", "");
}
```

the toast shows, but not the log. I do not wish to debug by toast, it's quite cumbersome, could anyone tell me what could possibly cause the log call to fail/not register/whatever it is it does?

Thanks!

Comment: I just closed Eclipse, reopened it, cleaned the project, no luck, the test() Log call still fails, while the onTouch() calls succeeds.

Comment: go to `DDMS` and make sure the android device is selected there!

Comment: check that the LogCat is your output

Comment: I now added this field to Player: Logger log = ....; and this call to the test() function: log.info("curiouser and curiouser"); - which passes through. I am very surprised by the two logs sided by side, only one of which works.

Comment: How are you viewing your logging output?

Comment: @barn.guml - do you mean I can set the Log to output elsewhere in code? I didn't, if it does it's on its own. Code-guru : I am using the logcat subwindow of Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure you want to tag each logcat with the method name?  It's usually much easier to tag with your application name and include the method name in the message then filter om the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Log._` does not work for empty messages. Do not know why :)

`Log.i("Player.test()", "hello..It will show");`

You need to give some message there!

Comment: Thank you, Mohsin, I could have searched until I got mad and never found that!